# Android: Slide animation via XML or Programming?

Tags: android, animation

I want sliding visible in android

Which way is better ?

XML :

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.startAnimation(fade_in);
```

Programming :

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.animate().translationY(-(view.getHeight())).alpha(0.0f);

view.animate().translationY(0).alpha(1.0f);
```

Notice: Programming code not work for me

Comment: Do you want fade in animation programatically?

Comment: @Ferdous Ahamed Does not matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fade In:**

```
view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(3000).start();
```

**Fade Out:**

```
view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(3000).start();
```

**XML vs Programming**

For `FadeIn` and `FadOut` animation you can use it `programmatically` from `java` code or `XML` as it seems simple.

For other animations, if you have any `parameters` in the `animation` that need to be determined `programmatically`, such as `speed`, `length of time`, then `programmatically` is the way to go, but using `XML` is just fine as well.